# Gitlab-runner fails to perform second job

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having a problem with the continuity of the task, where I create a GitLab-runner register and apply from the .gitlab-ci.yml file the register tag created it executes normally, however, if I perform a new commit or anything that needs to run it, it won't.

Image refers to the first job of the job successfully and second and another job of the job with error

[First image successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1U66.png)

[First image successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhtHb.png)

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGean.png)

Code below the file .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:latest
services:
 - docker:dind

stages:
 - master

build:
  stage: master
  only:
   - master
  tags:
   - prod
  script:
   - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache
   - sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Explanation of what I want to accomplish, I need to create a pipeline where every time I commit or change the branch master, I perform the git pull on my SSH server, and after downloading the changed version, after doing it, I will upload the application on the docker.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The CI file you've provided only has 1 job listed, so it's not possible that the "second job" fails because there is no second job

Comment: Arty-chan - About your comment I didn't understand much, in case you noticed something wrong, how can I mount my flow then?

Comment: I think to achieve what you want to do, what you have in the CI file should work. The issue you're having should be resolved by the answer.
What's a little confusing in the description is that it sounded like there should be two jobs in the same pipeline, but that doesn't seem to be case.

Answer (score 1):

Your runner is not setup appropriately. The user the gitlab runner runs as does not have permission to write/delete in the build directories. Use `chown`/`chmod` to change the permissions under `/home/gitlab-runner` to ensure the gitlab-runner user has permission to read/write/delete files.

Comment: Ok, i will test.

Comment: Same thing, to no avail.

Comment: It also looks like you're picking up the shell executor, not the docker executor. Make sure all the runners with the tag `prod` are running a _docker_ executor, not the _shell_ executor. Please provide a sanitized copy of your config.toml to your question for more help @HyagoLopes